# TFS Build release IIS Deployment Virtual path should begin with a / Error

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, devops

Virtual path should begin with a / Error is coming when I try to build ASP.NET Application.

[When I try to deploy following error massage come](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfTFP.png)

2017-12-07T22:14:15.6196402Z ##[section]Starting: Release
2017-12-07T22:14:15.6217147Z Current agent version: 2.126.0
2017-12-07T22:14:16.7467026Z ##[section]Starting: Initialize Job
2017-12-07T22:14:16.7497604Z Prepare release directory.
2017-12-07T22:14:16.7507232Z ReleaseId=2, TeamProjectId=49dcec02-39e8-4590-82a2-ab110a875d7e, ReleaseDefinitionName=New Release Definition
2017-12-07T22:14:16.7547852Z Release folder: C:\vstsagent\A4_work\r1\a
2017-12-07T22:14:16.7709838Z Environment variables available are below.  Note that these environment variables can be referred to in the task (in the ReleaseDefinition) by replacing "_" with "." e.g. AGENT_NAME environment variable can be referenced using Agent.Name in the ReleaseDefinition:
2017-12-07T22:14:17.1451135Z Download all required tasks.
2017-12-07T22:14:17.1837731Z ##[section]Finishing: Initialize Job
2017-12-07T22:14:17.2162154Z ##[section]Starting: Download Artifacts
2017-12-07T22:14:17.2272283Z Creating artifacts directory: C:\vstsagent\A4_work\r1\a
2017-12-07T22:14:17.2611603Z Created artifacts directory: C:\vstsagent\A4_work\r1\a
2017-12-07T22:14:17.2611793Z Downloading artifact
2017-12-07T22:14:17.2630213Z Starting artifacts download...
2017-12-07T22:14:17.2656016Z Downloading linked artifact CIDemo-ASP.NET (PREVIEW)-CI of type Build...
2017-12-07T22:14:17.2692891Z Ensuring artifact folder C:\vstsagent\A4_work\r1\a\CIDemo-ASP.NET (PREVIEW)-CI exists and is clean.
2017-12-07T22:14:17.2763873Z Preparing to get the list of available artifacts from build
2017-12-07T22:14:17.7608040Z Preparing to download artifact: drop
2017-12-07T22:14:17.7677814Z Artifact Type: ServerDrop
2017-12-07T22:14:17.7678100Z Downloading artifact from file container: #/1049368/drop to target: C:\vstsagent\A4_work\r1\a\CIDemo-ASP.NET (PREVIEW)-CI\drop
2017-12-07T22:14:17.7681631Z Parallel download limit: 4
2017-12-07T22:14:17.7681855Z Download buffer size: 8192
2017-12-07T22:14:18.0849933Z Caching items under drop in the file container...
2017-12-07T22:14:18.2018057Z Caching complete. (116 ms)
2017-12-07T22:14:18.2223239Z Downloading file
2017-12-07T22:14:28.2769926Z Download complete.
2017-12-07T22:14:28.2777174Z 126 placed file(s): 126 downloaded, 0 empty
2017-12-07T22:14:28.2778130Z 24 MB downloaded at 2435 KB/sec. Download time: 00:00:10.0528421.
2017-12-07T22:14:28.2778657Z Downloaded linked artifact CIDemo-ASP.NET (PREVIEW)-CI
2017-12-07T22:14:28.2778827Z Finished artifacts download
2017-12-07T22:14:28.2818295Z ##[section]Finishing: Download Artifacts
2017-12-07T22:14:28.2842190Z ##[section]Starting: IIS Web App Manage
2017-12-07T22:14:28.3045728Z ==============================================================================
2017-12-07T22:14:28.3045901Z Task         : IIS Web App Manage
2017-12-07T22:14:28.3046054Z Description  : Create or update a Website, Web App, Virtual Directories, and Application Pool
2017-12-07T22:14:28.3046224Z Version      : 0.5.4
2017-12-07T22:14:28.3046352Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-12-07T22:14:28.3046498Z Help         : [More Information]
2017-12-07T22:14:28.3046664Z ==============================================================================

2017-12-07T22:14:30.0691429Z ##[error]Virtual path should begin with a /

2017-12-07T22:14:30.0892513Z ##[section]Finishing: IIS Web App Manage
2017-12-07T22:14:30.0966325Z ##[section]Finishing: Release

Comment: Could you please share the deploy logs? Seems related to your deployment setting or website settings.

Comment: hi @AndyLi-MSFT I have added the log please look at it

Comment: Please share your Release definition settings and focus on the conifuration with `IIS Web App Manage` step. Capture the screenshot is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the settings with the step **IIS Web App Manage**. Seems you did not set the **Virtual path** correctly.

> **Virtual path:**
>
> **Parameters for IIS Application configuration**:
>
> Enter the virtual path in IIS relative to the parent website. The
>   parent website must already exist. Example: to create an application
>   named `Site/Application` enter `/Application`.
>
> **Parameters for IIS Virtual Directory configuration**：
>
> Enter the virtual path in IIS relative to the parent website. The
>   parent website and application must already exist. Example: to create
>   a virtual directory named `Site/Application/VDir` enter
>   `/Application/Vdir`.

See [Deploy: IIS Web App Manage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/iis-manage#parameters-for-iis-application-configuration) for details.